# How to require login in Elixir Phoenix application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, elixir, phoenix-framework, google-oauth

I'm using the [OAuth2 example](https://github.com/scrogson/oauth2_example) (with Google) for authenticating my Phoenix web application.  Though my site requires the user always be logged in or authenticated.  There's no user registration or anonymous access.

I've got the OAuth2 part working using Google as the provider.  Though I'm not sure how to require that the user is redirected to the login page if they're not logged in.

**Can anyone provide a working code example?**

Here's my `web\router.ex`:

```
defmodule MyApp.Router do
  use MyApp.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
    plug :assign_current_user
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", MyApp do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack
    get "/users", UserController, :index
    get "/users/:id", UserController, :show
    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

  scope "/auth", MyApp do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack
    get "/:provider", AuthController, :index
    get "/:provider/callback", AuthController, :callback
    delete "/logout", AuthController, :delete
  end

  # Other scopes may use custom stacks.
  # scope "/api", MyApp do
  #   pipe_through :api
  # end

  # Fetch the current user from the session and add it to `conn.assigns`. This
  # will allow you to have access to the current user in your views with
  # `@current_user`.
  defp assign_current_user(conn, _) do
    assign(conn, :current_user, get_session(conn, :current_user))
  end
end
```

---

**UPDATE 05/23/2016**

Using part of the selected answer below, I got this working by modifying my `web\router.ex`:

```
defmodule MyApp.Router do
  use MyApp.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
    plug :assign_current_user
  end

  pipeline :authenticated do
    plug :authenticate
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", MyApp do
    pipe_through [:browser, :authenticated] # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    resources "/users", UserController, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create]
  end

  scope "/auth", MyApp do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/:provider", AuthController, :index
    get "/:provider/callback", AuthController, :callback
    delete "/logout", AuthController, :delete
  end

  # Other scopes may use custom stacks.
  # scope "/api", MyApp do
  #   pipe_through :api
  # end

  # Fetch the current user from the session and add it to `conn.assigns`. This
  # will allow you to have access to the current user in your views with
  # `@current_user`.
  defp assign_current_user(conn, _params) do
    assign(conn, :current_user, get_session(conn, :current_user))
  end

  defp authenticate(conn, _params) do
    if conn.assigns.current_user do
      conn
    else
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "You must be logged in.")
      |> redirect(to: "/auth/google")
      |> halt()
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never done it with OAuth2 but in a regular Phoenix application a kind of standard way to do it is using a function that will be passed to the plug in a controller. For example:

```
defmodule App.AdminController do 
  use App.Web, :controller
  plug :authenticate when action in [:index, :new, :create, :update, :delete]
```

with the function authenticate being:

```
  def authenticate(conn, _params) do
    if conn.assigns.current_user do
      conn
    else
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "You must be logged in to do that.")
      |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
      |> halt()
    end
  end
```

The function checks if there is a `current_user` assigned. If it has then the `conn` is passed as it his. If it is not, then a flash is inserted telling the user he must be logged in, the user is redirected to the front page and the conn is halted.

EDIT: Like you can see in the first snippet this will only work on the actions you specify. If you want to do it in the entire application then you can put it in a helper module.

EDIT2: You may refer to the Programming Phoenix book where this is explained more in-depth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Phoenix_Token_Auth in my website. It's quite straightforward if you read the wiki as there is an example provided.

https://github.com/manukall/phoenix_token_auth

Hope it is helpful for you!